# Prove that $E\left(x^2 \times \frac{1}{x} \right)= E(x)$

Tags: probability, proof-writing, expectation

Consider a random variable $X$, with $E(x)=\mu_x$ and $V(x)=\sigma^2_x$.

It seems intuitive to me that, for two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where $f(x) \times g(x)=x$, it must be true that

$$ E\left[f(x)g(x)\right]= E(x) = \mu_x $$

However, expanding this expected value leads to:

$$ E\left[f(x)g(x)\right] = E\left[f(x)\right]E\left[g(x)\right] +Cov\left[f(x),g(x)\right]$$

But I fail to see how the **right-hand side** in the above expression can be shown to be **always** equal to $\mu_x$, except in the trivial case where e.g. $f(x)=cx$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{c}$.

What about a less trivial case but still "simple", like $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: why should the expected value of $1/x$ exist?

Comment: @Math-fun According to a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables#First_moment), it will, as long as $\mu_x \neq 0$.

Comment: That's only valid if the expected value of $f(X)$ exists.

Comment: consider a normally dist. rv. with $\mu=1$. Then $E\frac1x$ does not exist.

Comment: @Math-fun Not sure why the Taylor method seem to be contradictory with [your case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution). In any case, how does this invalidate the issue? What is the incorrect step? Where does the inequality brakes? I just applied a trivial covariance definition.

Comment: @DanielFischer If we restrict ourselves to the case where the expected value of both functions exist, how can we prove this?

Comment: @luchonacho If all is well-defined, then this follows immediately from [the definition of covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Definition). What definition of covariance do you start with, for it to look unclear?

Comment: @ClementC. What I did was to take the expected value of a product, and rewrite it in terms of covariance and product of expected values. I would like to see the general proof using these elements. I just don't know how to proceed. For example, if you take $f(x)=g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, then the proof goes by using the formula of the variance of $f(x)$ in terms of expectations.

Comment: But what I fail to see is what you expect in terms of proof that the RHS is equal to the LHS. It 's equal to it by the very definition of the covariance... $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[XY] -  \mathbb{E}[X] \mathbb{E}[Y]$. You can try to compute integrals for specific cases to show special cases, but since you want a "general proof", well, here it is.

Comment: @ClementC. I want to prove that the RHS is equal to $E(x)$.